# Rails assets path is incorrect on new stage with CDN assets pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have a rails app that uses an S3 bucket for storing precompiled assets. This works great for the production stage.

I have created a new stage called 'staging' that is the same as the production stage. I have duplicated the S3 bucket and given it a different name.

However, when I go to deploy my rails app with the staging environment the app asset path is set to the production stages path.

How do I get the staging assets to point to the stating assets path?

Here is my config/environments/staging.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
# Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

# Read from yml file
config.before_configuration do
    env_file = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'local_env.yml')
    YAML.load(File.open(env_file)).each do |key, value|
    ENV[key.to_s] = value
    end if File.exists?(env_file)
end

# Code is not reloaded between requests.
config.cache_classes = true

# Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
# your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
# and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
# Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
config.eager_load = true

# Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

# Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
# Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
# For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like
# NGINX, varnish or squid.
# config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

# Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
# Apache or NGINX already handles this.
config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

# Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
# config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

# Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
config.assets.compile = true

# Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
# yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
config.assets.digest = true

# `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

# Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
# config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
# config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

# Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
# config.force_ssl = true

# Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
# when problems arise.
config.log_level = :debug

# Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
# config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

# Use a different logger for distributed setups.
# config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

# Use a different cache store in production.
# config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

# Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
# config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'
ENV["AWS_ASSET_DIRECTORY"] = 'website-assets-staging'
config.action_controller.asset_host = "//#{ENV["AWS_ASSET_DIRECTORY"]}.s3.amazonaws.com"

# Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
# Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
# config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

# Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
# the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
config.i18n.fallbacks = true

# Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

# Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

# Do not dump schema after migrations.
config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false

config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => "staging.website.com.au"}
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It appears the staging sever is running the app in the production stage. Not sure why it would be doing that...

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot, but could the provider you're hosting the site with be running the site in "production" mode?  For example, if you're using Heroku, everything is "production" even if you have a separate staging app.

Comment: My servers are hosted by BinaryLane and I don't use Heroku. Thanks though.